# How to sign Unity app bundle for google play games

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, signing

I need to sign my Android app bundle from Unity in order to upload it to Google Play. I have gone through the steps to sign it in three different versions; however when I build and upload I keep getting the error

To sign the app bundle in Unity 2019.2 I would open build settings, tick the arrow for build app bundle; then navigate to player settings; Publishing settings, create new keystore and alias with passwords. And build. Pretty much the same with 2019.1, and 2018.4.

Example:

[image: example]

I would expect the app bundle to be signed, and be uploaded; however google play keeps saying it is not signed.

Answer (score 7):

So the solution was quite simple. It would be nice if google where to give a more accurate error message.

I tried to build without the tick for google app bundle, which gives me a APK file rather than and AAB file. When uploading that file google gave a more accurate error message, that the APK was built in development build, so it wasn't signed.

Returning to build settings, if you remove the tick for development build and then build as an APK or AAB, it will sign the app and work for the upload!